# Cannot access Address Lists Container on Active Directory when PC joined the same domain

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I want to access Address Lists Container on Active Directory, and get all folders to build a tree view on my winform. Every thing is normal when my PC has not joined domain. At this time, I user domain name, user name, password to login AD and get all folders. Address Lists Container is parent folder (parent node on tree view).

But, In joined domain case, I login to AD without using username or password. In theory, I will access the folder and get all it's childrens. But actual results, I received the returned result which has many exceptions.

Firstly, I create a connection to AD.

```
public bool OpenConnection()
    {
        ActiveDirectoryConnection connection = new ActiveDirectoryConnection(IsInDomain);
        if (connection == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        _Connection = connection;
        return true;
    }
```

Here is connection variable's values in Immidiate Window:

```
?_Connection
    {mynamespace.ActiveDirectoryConnection}
        DomainName: ""
        IsInDomain: true
        m_bIsInDomain: true
        Password: ""
        UserName: ""
```

To check a PC if it has joined domain, I use the method bellow. As you can see, if a PC has not join domain, I use domain name, user name and password to authenticate it:

```
public bool IsConnected
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Connection.IsInDomain)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Connection.DomainName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Connection.UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Connection.Password))
            {
                return AuthenticateUser(_Connection.DomainName, _Connection.UserName, _Connection.Password);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
private bool InDomain()
    {
        Win32.NetJoinStatus status = Win32.NetJoinStatus.NetSetupUnknownStatus;
        IntPtr pDomain = IntPtr.Zero;
        int result = Win32.NetGetJoinInformation(null, out pDomain, out status);
        if (pDomain != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Win32.NetApiBufferFree(pDomain);
        }
        if (result == Win32.ErrorSuccess)
        {
            if (status == Win32.NetJoinStatus.NetSetupDomainName)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsInDomain
    {
        get
        {
            return InDomain();
        }
    }
```

Finally, I get the folder (root) on AD:

```
public DirectoryEntry GetExchangeRootDirectoryEntry()
    {
        string exchangeRootPath = string.Empty; 
        try
        {
            if (!IsConnected)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var root = _Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry("RootDSE");


            exchangeRootPath = string.Format("CN=Address Lists Container,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange, CN=Services, {0}", root.Properties["configurationNamingContext"].Value);
            return _Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry(exchangeRootPath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Write logs
        }
        return null;
    }
public DirectoryEntry GetLdapDirectoryEntry(string path)
    {
        if (IsInDomain)
        {
            return GetDirectoryEntry(path, "LDAP");
        }
        else
        {
            return GetDirectoryEntry(path, "LDAP://" + DomainName);
        }
    }
```

root variable's value in IW. It has some attributes which threw some exceptions. I don't know the reason why they occur, in joined domain case, they are normal:

```
?root
    {System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry}
        base {System.ComponentModel.Component}: {System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry}
        AuthenticationType: Secure
        Children: {System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries}
        Guid: {228d9a83-c302-11cf-9aa4-00aa004a5691}
        Name: "RootDSE"
        NativeGuid: "{228D9A83-C302-11CF-9AA4-00AA004A5691}"
        NativeObject: {System.__ComObject}
        ObjectSecurity: 'root.ObjectSecurity' threw an exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException'
        Options: {System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntryConfiguration}
        Parent: {System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry}
        Path: "LDAP://RootDSE"
        Properties: {System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection}
        SchemaClassName: null
        SchemaEntry: 'root.SchemaEntry' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
        UsePropertyCache: true
        Username: null

?exchangeRootPath
    "CN=Address Lists Container,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange, CN=Services, CN=Configuration,DC=cadomain,DC=com"

?_Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry(exchangeRootPath)
    {System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry}
        base {System.ComponentModel.Component}: {System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry}
        AuthenticationType: Secure
        Children: {System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries}
        Guid: '_Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry(exchangeRootPath).Guid' threw an exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException'
        Name: '_Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry(exchangeRootPath).Name' threw an exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException'
        NativeGuid: '_Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry(exchangeRootPath).NativeGuid' threw an exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException'
        NativeObject: '_Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry(exchangeRootPath).NativeObject' threw an exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException'
        ObjectSecurity: '_Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry(exchangeRootPath).ObjectSecurity' threw an exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException'
        Options: '_Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry(exchangeRootPath).Options' threw an exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException'
        Parent: '_Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry(exchangeRootPath).Parent' threw an exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException'
        Path: "LDAP://CN=Address Lists Container,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange, CN=Services, CN=Configuration,DC=cadomain,DC=com"
        Properties: {System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection}
        SchemaClassName: '_Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry(exchangeRootPath).SchemaClassName' threw an exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException'
        SchemaEntry: '_Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry(exchangeRootPath).SchemaEntry' threw an exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException'
        UsePropertyCache: true
        Username: null
```

OK, my ultimate goal is that I want to get _Connection.GetLdapDirectoryEntry(exchangeRootPath). But now it has many exceptions. I dont understand why I cannot get the root when my PC joined domain. In not joined domain case, everthing is normal.

Could you tell me the reason why it happends? And how to get the root in joined domain case without using username and password to authenticate user?

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

Being joined to the domain does not mean you don't then have to supply credentials when connecting to Active Directory. Your connection will be using an anonymous login without credentials which probably doesn't have permissions to do what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for commentary. I solve the problem myself =)